# Why do we restart server on change in file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Why do we have to restart server on some change in an `.html` file or a server file? But we don't have to restart server when we make a change in jQuery file.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that changes the server state will require that state to be updated. When you change your server side code, such as adding a new route, modifying the behavior of an existing route, changing html templates, or anything that modifies the execution of code on the server, you have update the state of the server to your changes.  The easiest way to do this is through a restart because typically all the code is loaded up when the application starts.

Statically served files don't require a server restart because the code that handles them in your server hasn't changed, they just pass the file on to whoever requested it.  When these files change, you can just reload the app in browser instead.

Comment: I cannot understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Can you please provide me some detailed information